# Is there a reason not to use Backbone.Model on node.js backend?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I was thinking ... when I code a web app using `Backbone.js`, most of the time I duplicate the models : one version for the backend in language `X`, using ORM `Y`, one for the frontend using Backbone. A lot of validation in common, same sh*t for generating urls, etc ... I just started with `Node.js`, and I thought that since you can run a lot of the same code on the backend and frontend, why not using Backbone.js models for the backend as well, so that there would be less code duplication ? I couldn't find info about that ... any pointers ? Is it a bad idea and why ? I can only guess that in that case you'd have to write your `Backbone.sync` for database persistence.

**EDIT**

Practical issues that need to be solved to achieve that :

1. `Backbone.sync` to work with mongodb (or whatever database is used).
2. building the client-side javascript file with node.js files, possible solution : [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out for a while building the backend with `Backbone`, I found it was total overkill, and brought more problems than simplifications. Instead I rolled back to using simple wrappers around `mongodb`.

My initial thought in using Backbone was sharing url generation and model validation between backend and frontend. But as a matter of fact you don't need Backbone for that.
So I wrote reusable functions for validation and url generation, and used `browserify` to make them available client-side.

Of course this might all change in the future if more people build tools for running Backbone backend-side ... but at the time of the writing, Backbone is definitely not made for that, and there's no library to help adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit outdated, but interesting nevertheless: [Re-using Backbone.js Models on the server with Node.js and Socket.io to build real-time apps](http://andyet.net/blog/2011/feb/15/re-using-backbonejs-models-on-the-server-with-node/)

A library to replace the default Backbone.sync by persisting to couchDB, when using Backbone on node.js: [node-backbone-couch](https://github.com/saimonmoore/node-backbone-couch)

Comment: Yeah ... I'v found that, but it doesn't really answer to the practical questions (which I'll put in the initial question)